# Is there anything similar to Junit Setup Method in Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following scenario

```
 interface DAO
 {
      String a();
      String b();
      String c();

 }
```

I create a mock of this DAO interface and I feed it to something called DAOProcess. Inside DAOProcess, I have various methods calling DAO methods a, b and c.

Now each time I need to unit test a method in DAOProcess, I'll end up writing `when(mockDAO.a()).thenReturn("test")`.

Is there anyway I can move these `when(mockDAO.a()).thenReturn("test")` common to all the test cases ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your test cases are all in one class you could make use of a method annotated with `@Before`, e.g.:

```
...
private DAO mockDAO;

@Before 
public void setUp() {
    mockDAO = mock(DAO.class);
    when(mockDAO.a()).thenReturn("test");
    ...etc...
}    
...
```

Or, if you need the behaviour over many test classes you could write a utility class to set behaviour on a Mock instance, e.g.:

```
public class MockDAOPrototype {
    public DAO getMockWithDefaultBehaviour() {
        final DAO mockDAO = mock(DAO.class);
        when(mockDAO.a()).thenReturn("test");
        ...etc...

        return mockDAO;
    }
}
```

And then call `MockDAOPrototype.getMockWithDefaultBehaviour()` in your `setUp` method.

Answer (score 5):

You can create an AbstractTestCase class that is `abstract` and is extended by all test cases where you need this mock. In that abstract test case, you will have the following statements.

```
 @Ignore // just in case your runner thinks this is a JUnit test.
 public abstract class AbstractTestCase
 {
      @Mock
      private DAO mockDAO;

      @Before
      private void setupMocks()
      {
           when(mockDAO.a()).thenReturn("test")
           ....
      }
 }
```

In your concrete test case classes, you would

```
 public class MyConcreteTestCase extends AbstractTestCase
 {
      @InjectMocks
      @Autowired
      private DAOProcess daoProcess;

      ....
 }
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the Autowired annotation here, as it might be confusing with spring stuff. Even if DAOProcess was build in a Spring context, I'm not sure ti would be a wise idea to replace the references of the collaborator by mocks, while these beams are still managed by spring!